# Access to the path 'D:\inetpub <dir list here> is denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm trying to upload file to my shared hosting and getting this error MSG, 
Is it something I should do or I need the hosting to deal with?

```
Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\inetpub ...
ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource.
```

Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose `"Properties"` and select the Security tab. Click `"Add"` to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account and check the boxes for the desired access.

Comment: This is probably a question that you should ask your hosting provider.

Comment: Usually it is because your application pool identity didn't have access to the target folder, check this article: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: This is only permision error. I believe you just need to ask your hosting provider to give full permission to your folder.

Comment: it was application pool problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, you just need to understand and master some steps that all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).